# Is it just me or does the back button in Google Chrome not always work?

Tags: google-chrome

Its strange, but a lot of the time I find myself clicking the back button a few times before it seems to work.

Is this just me with this issue, or has anyone else experienced this with Chrome?

Comment: Just you?  Haven't run across that problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Sometimes when Chrome is loading a page, and only somtimes ALL buttons are unresponsive just for a sec, its during this time the back button won't work.

The only workaround I can think of is to get into the habit of waiting for ALL page content to load before you click the back button.

Answer (score 2):

I had a click and drag issue the other day, my mouse was connected to a usb hub, I connected it directly to the PC and the problem was gone.

Comment: I've had exactly the same issue a long time ago with a really crappy hub and cordless mouse.  A little more recently I had a similar problem due to my mouse batteries being low.

Comment: I don't think it was my hub, it worked for months before acting up and everything else connected to it works fine, I would blame usb plug and pray first...wonderful when it works, a nightmare when it does not.